# Submit form, add input to URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a regular form with a single input:

```
{{ Form::open(array('id' => 'form_search')) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::text('search', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Search...')) }}
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

When the form is submitted, I want it to redirect to a page showing the results by the following URL:

```
http://www.website.com/search/<QUERY_HERE>
```

For example, if someone typed `john` in the form input and submitted the form, the URL redirected to would look like:

```
http://www.website.com/search/john
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your routes.php

```
//Handle form submit
Route::get('search', 'YourSearchController@yourSearchFunction');
//Return results
Route::get('search/{search}', 'YourSearchController@yourSearchResults');
```

Then add the route to your form:

```
{{Form::open(['route' => 'search'])}}
```

Then in yourSearchController:

```
function yourSearchFunction() {
    $search = Input::only(['search']);
    return Redirect::to('search/'.$search);
}
```

Then also in yourSearchController:

```
function yourSearchResults($search) {
    return View::make('results')->with(compact('search'));
}
```